# DAC Output to 4-20mA

Tags: dac, 4-20ma

I have a Microcontroller with a DAC output of 0-3.3V. What external circuitry can I use to convert it into a 4-20mA current transmitter.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want 0-3.3V converted linearly to 4-20mA?  For instance, 0Vin means 4mA out?

Comment: I have made good experiences with the [XTR111](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr111.pdf) Chip from Texas Instruments. It needs a high voltage supply though.

Comment: It could be 0-20mA as well, but preferably want 4-20mA. How come this is not usually done (google search didn't bring up anything useful). Is this normally not done?

Comment: @d3l Yeah, ideally looking to power it from 5V supply. Thanks though for the chip recommendation!

Comment: Anything with a 5 volt input would likely have an integrated step-up converter. It has to be able to maintain a 20 mA current over potentially very long cables, and it has to be able to drive at least some load on the receiving end. That requires the ability to increase the voltage, if necessary. Search for _current loop compliance voltage_.

Answer (score 0):

you could have the DAC in series with a 165 ohm resistor, although this would only give you the right current if the other end of the resistor is grounded. it's not a proper current source, but if you use it to drive a current mirror, that could work.